# VSCode wrong path while debugging Go program

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have my main.go in a subfolder `cmd/admin/main.go` but when I'm debugging and there are errors in a file, it gives me the relative path from the main.go folder instead of the workspace folder. So for example I will have the error `..\..\path\to\file.go:238:3: undefined: test` which won't work if I try to Ctrl+click it.
If I launch the command from the root `go run cmd/admin/main.go` that works as intended returning `path\to\file.go:238:3: undefined: test`.

My launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/admin",
      "env": {},
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Go version 1.16.6
VSC version 1.58.2
OS Windows10

Comment: Is it Go 1.6.6 or Go 1.16.6? Does your project have `go.mod`/`go.sum` files?

Comment: Sorry Go 1.16.6, both go.mod and go.sum present

Answer (score 9):

Go File > Add Folder to Workspace
Then select the folders containing main.go
[image]
You can also do it in the command line:

```
code cmd/admin -a
```

Now make sure your current launch.json has been deleted to start fresh, your workspace should look like this:

[image]

Notice that there is a 'package main' and 'func main()' this is required for Go to know the entry point.

Now press Run and Debug with a breakpoint:

[image]

That's it, it should now work on any folders you add to your workspace. If you want more specific debug options, add them to your workspace and they'll apply in the context of the file you run from. Click the 'create a launch.json file.:

[image]

Select workspace:

[image]

Select Go: Launch package

[image]

You now have a launch config that will apply to the directory you run it from:

[image]

Make sure to save your workspace to keep it:

[image]

#### Notes

- Be sure to delete your current launch.json files if they already exist anywhere.
- Make sure all of your source code is located in GOPATH/src, you can find out where GOPATH is by putting this into a command line:

```
go env GOPATH
```

- The file doesn't need to be named main.go, but you MUST have a package named main, and a func named main for Go to know the entry point, for each executable, for example influxdb's two cli's: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/tree/master/cmd

#### More info

VS Code workspace debugging:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_debugging

GOPATH: https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code

Comment: Trying that I just get different path errors when I click on the the link, the base launch.json will give me `c:\Users\shado\Projects\path\to\file.go` while the new workspace launch.json will give me `c:\Users\shado\Projects\PROJECT-X\cmd\path\to\file.go`
the correct path should be `c:\Users\shado\Projects\PROJECT-X\path\to\file.go` without the cmd. I guess that's progress.

Comment: @Shadoweb In a command prompt put in "go env GOPATH" This shows you were all your source code should go to work with Go tooling like modules. Looks like you're on Windows, so should put all your Go source code in here: c:\Users\shado\go\src\PROJECT-X\ Then delete your current launch.json, add the two subfolders to workspace, and add the debug configurations. Should work. I'll update answer to include this info.

Comment: Actually by replacing TEST with panic("TEST") it does work. I suppose I was trying to solve a typo issue instead of a real issue, which would almost never happen anyway... I suppose  I can live with that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shadoweb not a problem happy you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try and make sure:

- you have no `GOxxx` environment variable set (no `GO_BASE_PATH`, no `GOROOT`), except for `GOPATH` set to `%USERPROFILE%\go`, and `%GOPATH%\bin` in your `%PATH%`
- you are using Go installed in the default `C:\Program Files\Go\` folder
- you have set up your project [using Go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules), with a `go mod init myproject`
- you have [defined a multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_multiroot-workspaces) for your project root folder, compose of only one root: your project. Save that workspace (it will create a `<name>.code-workspace` JSON file).

See then if the issue persists (and no `cwd` should be needed in your `launch.json`)

Comment: I have the folder in C:\dev\Go, but does that really matter? I created the project a long time ago with `go mod init` but made updates using VSC.
I tried the multi-root workspace but it still fails on the Ctrl+click, it will only move up 1 folder instead of 2 and stops at `${workspaceFolder}/cmd`. I suppose that's some progress.

Comment: @Shadoweb Not sure: I am just describing my setup, where delve works perfectly (make sure to update your Go tools, by the ways)